# How to reduce the execution time in C# while calling an API?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, desktop-application, windows

I am creating a windows application (using windows form application) which calls the web service to fetch data. In data, I have to fetch 200+ clients information and for each client, I have to fetch all users information. A client can have 50 to 100 users. So, I am calling web service in a loop (after getting all clients list) for each client to fetch the users listing. This is a long process. I want to reduce the execution time for this whole process. So, please suggest me which approach can help in reducing the execution time which is currently up to 40-50 mins for one time data fetch. Let me know any solution like multithreading or any thing else, whichever is best suited to my application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in control of the web service, have a method that returns all the clients at once instead of 1 by one to avoid rountrips as Michael suggested.

If not, make sure to make as many requests at the same time (not in sequence) to avoid as much laterncy as possible. For each request you will have at least 1 rountrip (so at least your ping's Worth of delay), if you make 150 requests then you'll get your ping to the server X 150 Worth of "just waiting on the network". If you split those requests in 4 bunches, and do each of these bunches in parallel, then you'll only wait 150/4*ping time. So the more requests you do concurrently, the least you wait.

Comment: Hi Ronan,

Thanks for your reply. So, I have to implement the multi-threading and have to start a new thread for every 4 client to fetch the data of users. Right?

Comment: @atul No, starting a thread is very slow, you need to read up on multithreading, this is a subject way to complex to fit in a stackoverflow answer, pick up a book on it. But the gist of it is you need to pre allocate sufficient threads (typically around number of virtual cores, HT included, X2 is a good tradeoff for many workloads) and keep as many of those in use as possible (so each request gets allocated to the first unused thread).

Comment: @atul Also note in case that wasn't clear, if you can get the first option (getting the web service to provide the full list at once), it will always be MASSIVELY faster. So i'd go down that road first (even if i wasn't in control of the service, i'd request a change to whoever provides it, odds are they'll be happy to comply because else you will be hammering their servers with hundreds of requests instead of well, one!)

Comment: @@ronan Thanks. I will look more into the stuff you have suggested regarding the multi-threading. As I do not have control to web services because these are third party web service that I am consuming for my application.

Still, I will ask to their support if they can provide me all data in one web service call.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to avoid calling the service in a loop for every user to get the details, but instead do that loop in the server and return all the data in one-shot, otherwise you will suffer of a lot of useless latencies caused by the thousand of calls, and not just because of the server time or data-transferring time.

This is also a pattern, called [Remote Facade](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/remoteFacade.html) or [Facade Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) explained by Martin Fowler and the Gang of Four:

> any object that's intended to be used as a remote objects needs a coarse-grained interface that minimizes the number of calls needed to get some-thing done [...] Rather than ask for an order and its order lines individually, you need to access and update the order and order lines in a single call.

Comment: Hi Michael,

Thanks for your reply. I do not have in control to the web-service so can not make changes in the web service. So, it will not work for this case.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're not in control of the web service, you could try to use a Parallel.ForEach loop instead of a ForEach loop to query the web service.

The MSDN has a tutorial on how to use it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi Guillaume,

Thanks for your reply. I will check and implement this.

Comment: @atul Good. Let me know if this fixes your problem.